# Randomly xml tags are not showing in the elasticsearch

Tags: xml, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch 7.14.0.
When I check the JSON format of a message in the elasticsearch, I can see below.

```
"agent": {
  "ephemeral_id": "2a4c1cb3-b7d6-4a1b-b244-0e669f1d7686",
  "type": "filebeat",
  "id": "3dfa6feb-ff2c-441b-9304-c54254014cfa",
  "version": "7.14.0",
  "name": "cbc-deg",
  "hostname": "cbc-deg"
},
"message": "[2022-04-22 12:35:07,330] [http-nio-8080-exec-9] INFO  [my-project,21bd73f872d330f0,ded0bf0fbea5bd9e,55883575-3768-41d3-96ea-b71f506658d2] m.service.testService - PRE- calling to FC2PS with req FC: FcAccountTransferReq() req PS: \n<TRANSACTION><SERVICETYPE>VCDECLINE</SERVICETYPE>\n<SEN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>333333</SEN_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>\n<INITIATERWINGID>1222222</INITIATERWINGID>\n<CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>\n<AMOUNT>0</AMOUNT>\n<REFAMOUNT>3.99</REFAMOUNT>\n<REMARK>444444</REMARK>\n<ENTITY_CODE>FC</ENTITY_CODE>\n<ACCOUNT_NO>9999999</ACCOUNT_NO>\n<SOURCE>WEB</SOURCE>\n</TRANSACTION>\n",
```

But when I check it from elasticsearch UI I can see below.No XML tags. Only the XML nodes contents.

[image]

XML message previewing issue is happening randomly. Do I need to add any encoding mechanism to the elasticsearch?

Thanks,

Comment: When you view the HTML source of that screenshot, are the XML tags showing up there?

Comment: I can see XML tags in the HTML source.

Comment: Then this means you found a bug, and a pretty embarrassing one at that. They are not HTML-encoding their output properly, which might even open them up for an injection attack. That's a GitHub issue, not a Stack Overflow question.